Adding unique functionality to each instance of a scriptable object
I am working on an AR Pokemon game in Unity for a university project. While I am not handling the AR component yet, I am stuck trying to implement unique functionality for each card I create.
I have a class called PokemonCard which inherits from CardBase which is a scriptable object.
using UnityEngine;
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Card/Pokemon Card", fileName = "new Pokemon Card")]
public class PokemonCard : CardBase
{    
  
    [SerializeField]
    public PokemonMove[] Moves;

    public Energy Type;
    public Energy[] Weakenesses;
    public Energy[] Resistances;

    public PokemonCard evolvedFrom = null;
    [SerializeField]
    int maxHP;
    [SerializeField]
    int currentHP;
}

When I create a new Pokemon Card, I want to be able to assign it with functions that represent the moves available for the card. For example, I want a Hitmonlee card to have 2 moves, "Jab" which is represented by a function that does 40 damage, and "Punch" which is represented by another function that does 70 damage.
I cant seem to find any information on how I can attach these functions to the scriptable object so that they can be called.
If you need further clarification I'm happy to provide it!
If using scriptable objects is not optimal, please let me know if there's another data structure I can use to store all this information and allow unique functionality

You would create a PokemonMove scriptable object instance for each move, and assign them to the respective card(s).  This makes sense since most moves are shared between different pokemon.  The actual use of these would be through behaviour scripts.  Scriptable objects are the static data, and is appropriate for this type of modeling.

It would be best if you use MonoBenaviour for the implementation of functionality.
At the same time, you may keep the static data in a scriptable object and access it from MonoBenaviour.

Yeah i had a think about it. I guess i was being stubborn trying to use ScriptableObjects. I've decided to use just prefabs with monobehaviours attached holding unique functionality. Thanks
